# I want to import all my table data to xml in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

```html
controller.rb

def xml_print
    byebug
    @month = params[:month]
    @year = params[:year]
    @maps = SalaryMapSap.all
    @salaryslip = Salaryslip.limit(50)
                                                                                                          
    respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { send_data render_to_string(:index), :filename => 'mydoc.xml', :type=>"application/xml", :disposition => 'attachment' }
    # @salary_components = SalaryComponent.all
    @maps = SalaryMapSap.all
  end
end

routes.rb

resources :salaryslip_components do
    collection do
      post :xml_print
    end
 end

new.html.erb

<%= bootstrap_form_for(:salaryslip_component, url: { action: 'xml_print',format: 'xml',month: @month,year: @year}) do |f| %>
```

I want to generate an XML Data in rails,for that i have created one form,in that two drop downs are there where i would select month and year and on bottom there would be submit button,if i click on it then all my data would be downloaded as an XML.I created index XML builder file.But my data is not generating in XML ,error is coming,that action could not be found.I also mentioned this in controller's action.

```html
format.xml { send_data render_to_string(:index), :filename => 'mydoc.xml', :type=>"application/xml", :disposition => 'attachment' }
```

So please help me.

Comment: When there's an error shown, it's better to include its exact text into the question

Comment: Also please include your routes for that controller and method/action name

Comment: i have included the routes....pls see..